# Django content-type : how do I get an object?

Tags: django

If I have a django content_type reference (the id of the model.class and the id of the object), what's the best way to get the actual object itself?

Sounds trivial but I can't actually see an example anywhere.

Comment: Do you want [`get_object_for_this_type`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#django.contrib.contenttypes.models.ContentType.get_object_for_this_type)?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

From memory, it is something like this:

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
ct = ContentType.objects.get_for_id(content_type)
obj = ct.get_object_for_this_type(pk=object_id)
```

Comment: I'd like to point out that calling the argument `content_type` is somewhat misleading. `get_for_id` expects the content_type id